# Interesting observation about applying DCT to a matrix

Tags: matrix, dct

I have a grayscale image 512x512 in size. I want to transform the matrix into dct so here is what I did.

Scenario 1: Applying DCT to the whole image

`img = imread('cameraman.tif');`

`img_dct = dct2(img);`

Scenario 2: Applying DCT to the very first 8x8 block of the original image

`img2 = imread('cameraman.tif);`

`img_block = img2(1:8, 1:8);`

`img_block_dct = dct2(img_block);`

Now, here comes the interesting bit (or I have done something wrong)
When I display `img_dct(1:8, 1:8)` and `img_block_dct` I get two very different 8x8 matrices. Shouldn't these two be exactly the same or am I mistaken?

Comment: No, they should not be the same. You've computed two completely different things.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, I do not understand. All I am doing is applying dct to the whole image and at the same time only getting an 8x8 block from the original image and applying dct to that block.

Comment: Exactly. In the first, the output values depend on the entire image, in the second they only depend on the 8x8 region.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, oh k so that means if I need any 8x8 block from the image which consists of DCT coefficients, I will first need to transform the WHOLE image into DCT and then extract an 8x8 block?

Comment: It depends on what your aim is.  Most compression algorithms work by dividing the original image up into blocks, and then computing the DCT of each block separately.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth, thanks for the advice. it turns out I wrote the function wrong. You are absolutely right. First divide the image in 8x8 blocks and then compute the DCT of each individual block.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be same.  Go through the `DCT2` equation, `DCT` coefficients depends on size of the image.  If you do block wise `M=8` `N=8`, else it will be size of the image.